# Using AWS Rekognition in a google cloud function

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, amazon-rekognition

I am very new to AWS and was wondering if it was possible to use AWS Rekognition in a Google Cloud Function that pulls images from Google Cloud Storage? If so, what are the keys steps to getting this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Many [Amazon Rekognition API calls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) involve interaction with files stored in Amazon S3. These API calls will *not* work with Google Cloud Storage.

Some API calls allow images to be passed as part of the call. These will work from any environment.